# "touchstart" event used for a "doubletap" prevents scroll working on swipe up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a "touchstart" event to a "tbody" so a function ocurrs when I doubletap on a row. This works perfectly BUT prevents scroll up or down in mobile (so if my table has enough rows, you'll get stuck)

```
//DoubleClick not working on doubleTap, so...
$("tbody").on("touchstart", tapHandler);
var tapedTwice = false;
function tapHandler(e) {
    
    if(!tapedTwice) {
        tapedTwice = true;
        setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = false; }, 300 ); //doubletap speed
        return false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();//Prevents zoom, but without it, scroll still not working
    lightboxPrint(e);  //Fx for this event
 }
```

Already try deleting all CSS and Bootstrap. Only function that gives promblems is this one.
If this can be fixed, can I add a new event for "swipe up" or "swipe down" to scroll?

Comment: You’re returning false for the ground state where `tapedTwice` is false. This means the touch start event is cancelled and users can never trigger scrolling. Instead of returning false, wrap the statement after the if block in an else block.

Comment: Terry is ABSOLUTELY RIGHT! Returning false prevents everything "normal" to happen, so I did "the opposite way.
var tapedTwice = true;
function tapHandler(e) {
    
    if(tapedTwice) {
        tapedTwice = false;
        setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = true; }, 300 );
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    lightboxPrint(e);  
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm answering with Terry's words, just to close the question. He should get full credit.**
Instead of starting with "tapedTwice = false", I just started with "tapedTwice = true" and change the funtion accordingly.

```
$("tbody").on("touchstart", tapHandler);
var tapedTwice = true;
function tapHandler(e) {
    
    if(tapedTwice) {
        tapedTwice = false;
        setTimeout( function() { tapedTwice = true; }, 300 );
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();//Para evitar el zoom
    lightboxPrint(e);  
};
```